# Como fazer o Binding da Visibilidade de uma Label conforme o tamanho de uma Lista

Tags: c#, wpf, propriedade, binding

Tenho uma lista de objetos do tipo "BasicVariable", um `ObservableCollection` deles, e preciso que a Interface Gráfica mostre uma Label quando o número de itens desta collection passar de 1000, acho que o binding está correto mas não consegui uma maneira em que seja atualizado o contador e a UI a cada adição/remoção de um objeto desta classe...

Aqui está o label que preciso atualizar:

```
<Label x:Name="configFilePath_Copy" Content="BasicVariable can't exceed 1000" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,11,62" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="154" Foreground="Red">
  <Label.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BVExceed}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

Aqui cololquei uma propriedade booleana que retorna se tem ou não mais de 1000 objetos

```
public bool BVExceed
{
  get { return NumberOfBasicVariablesExceeded(); }
  set
  {
    if(value != NumberOfBasicVariablesExceeded())
    {
      NumberOfBasicVariablesExceeded();
      RaisePropertyChanged("BVExceeded");
    }
  }
}
```

Aqui o método que interage com a outra viewmodel que possui a `observablecollection`

```
public bool NumberOfBasicVariablesExceeded()
{
  if (BasicVariableViewModel != null)
  { return (BasicVariableViewModel.BasicVariables.Count >= 1000); }
  else
    return false; 
}
```

Como sou novo no padrão MVVM e no WPF, sei que minha implementação está errada tanto no código quanto no XAML, gostaria de entender exatamente como é o padrão de se fazer esse binding de datatriggers para poder implementar corretamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, a questão que eu vejo é que sua variável `BVExceed` não é alterada. Tenta colocar o método `NumberOfBasicVariablesExceeded()` junto com o add ou remove da sua collection e o retorno dele você atribui na variável `BVExceed`.

no caso seu BVExceed ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
private bool _bvExceed;
public bool BVExceed
{
  get { return _bvExceed; }
  set
  {
      _bvExceed = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("BVExceed");
  }
}
```

e dentro do seu método add/remove você chama o `NumberOfBasicVariablesExceeded()`

```
BVExceed = NumberOfBasicVariablesExceeded();
```

Comment: Entendi, mas agora vi que existe um método que dá pra usar de OnCollectionChanged, usando um NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs... Nao ficaria mais correto usando isso? Estou sentindo que o que estou fazendo no programa atualmente é meio gambiarra